# Call my Anki add-on's Python function from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, anki

How can I let my add-on's JavaScript (loaded in the reviewer's webview) communicate request values from my add-on's Python parts?

`pycmd` doesn't seem able to do this, because as far as I can see there is no way for the receiving python to return a value to the calling JS:

```
name="webview_did_receive_js_message",
args=["handled: tuple[bool, Any]", "message: str", "context: Any"],
return_type="tuple[bool, Any]",
doc="""Used to handle pycmd() messages sent from Javascript.

Message is the string passed to pycmd().
For messages you don't want to handle, return 'handled' unchanged.

If you handle a message and don't want it passed to the original
bridge command handler, return (True, None).

If you want to pass a value to pycmd's result callback, you can
return it with (True, some_value).
        
Context is the instance that was passed to set_bridge_command().
It can be inspected to check which screen this hook is firing
in, and to get a reference to the screen. For example, if your
code wishes to function only in the review screen, you could do:
    if not isinstance(context, aqt.reviewer.Reviewer):
        # not reviewer, pass on message
        return handled

    if message == "my-mark-action":
        # our message, call onMark() on the reviewer instance
        context.onMark()
        # and don't pass message to other handlers
        return (True, None)
    else:
        # some other command, pass it on
        return handled
""",
```

[Anki's `gui_hook`s](https://github.com/ankitects/anki/blob/main/qt/tools/genhooks_gui.py#L618)

So code like my first idea

```py
from typing import Any

from aqt import gui_hooks

def handle_calls(handled: tuple[bool, Any], message: str, context: Any) -> tuple[bool, Any]:
    if not message.startswith('myaddon:'):
        return handled
    # handle my custom message ...
    return (True, None) # but how to give the JavaScript information??

gui_hooks.webview_did_receive_js_message(handle_calls)
```

seems like a dead-end.

I surprisingly get an error from that code too:

```
    gui_hooks.webview_did_receive_js_message(handle_calls)
TypeError: __call__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'message' and 'context'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you ever succeeded in solving this issue, but according to aqt's gui_hooks, returning a tuple of true value and your message `return (True, "your message")` should pass the message to pycmd. However, it is not working for me. But a quick workaround fix can be the following, which works good enough for me:

```
from aqt.gui_hooks import webview_did_receive_js_message
from aqt.reviewer import Reviewer
from aqt import mw

class Message_Handler:
    def __init__(self):
        webview_did_receive_js_message.append(self.handle_search_query)

    def handle_search_query(self, handled, message:str, context):
        if not isinstance(context, Reviewer):
            return handled

        mw.web.eval(f"test = {message}")
        mw.web.eval(f"console.log(\"{message} receeived\")")
        return (True, None)
```